# Ruby gsub issues

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a piece of text that resembled the following:

```
==EXCLUDE

#lots of lines of text

==EXCLUDE

#this is what I actually want
```

And so I was trying to remove the unwanted bit by doing:

```
str.gsub!(/==EX.*?==EXCLUDE/, '')
```

However, its not working. When I tried to remove the \n chars first, it worked like a dream. The issue is that I can't actually remove the \n characters. How can I do a substitution like this while leaving newlines in place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, the `.` does not match line break chars. If you enable the `m` modifier in Ruby (in other languages, this is the `s` modifier) it should work:

```
str.gsub!(/==EX.*?==EXCLUDE/m, '')
```

Here's a live demo on Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/YxLSB1Iq95

Answer (score 2):

Try `str.gsub!(/==EX.*?==EXCLUDE/m, '')`

That should make it span new lines.

Comment: Assuming you want to retain line breaks for the `==EXCLUDE` lines, the second gsub arg should probably be "\n\n".